# Any way to selectively enable/disable debugging on android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I'm porting a java application from windows to android. The app starts by loading a large array from disk. (4 meg of data into a 1 million element class array)

When run or debugged on windows in eclipse, it takes 8 seconds to load.

When run from eclipse on the android without debugging it takes 50 seconds, which seems a bit slow but if that is what it is, that is what it is.

When debugged from eclipse on the android it takes 8 minutes to load. On the android emulator I gave up after 40 minutes.

My question is of there is any way to tell the debugger to not debug this portion of the code?

Or is there anything which can be turned off/on in eclipse which could speed debugging till the app is past the initialization?

Comment: Run the app in release mode instead? Just deploy it to the device and use it.

Comment: I need to debug the app at a point past the initialization. The windows app used a buffereimage, which on android needs to be changed to use a bitmap.

Comment: the debugger is slower than just running the code out right. Is that array load in a seperate thead because it should be if it isnt that could be the problem

Comment: My question is if there are any tricks which can be used in the debugger to speed code which has no need to be debugged. In C, I could compile one file with debugging and another without debugging, which when linked the debugger would only debug the code with debugging and run the code without debugging at full speed.

I'm currently investigating alternative coding which will execute faster, but that would be a whole other discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would most likely be through the DDMS perspective in eclipse.

Run your app on the device as you usually would (the method that currently takes around 50 seconds to start).

Once the app has started switch to the DDMS perspective (usually in the top right of eclipse, you may have to add/open the perspective if you have not used it before just by clicking the add button and finding DDMs in the pop up window).

Once you are in the DDMS perspective your device and any processes running on it should show in the devices tab in this perspective (on the left by default). Once the initial load has completed you can select you app process from the list and enable the debugger on it by clicking the green debugging icon.

If you would then like to stop debugging later on in the same run just switch to the Debug perspective, right click on your project (in the Debug tab, it should have a name similar to "Project Name [Android Application]") and click disconnect.

Unfortunately I do not think there is a way to disable debugging programmatically, however it would be nice to see added (if has not been already!)

As an aside there was a talk given at Google I/O 2009 about debugging on Android that has a section on method tracing ([Debugging Arts of the Ninja Masters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dgnx0E7m1GQ)) which may help you find a way to speed up that initial load if you are looking to do so.

Comment: BINGO!!! This worked perfectly!!! The application is a camera application, which allowed for debugging to be turned on after the program initialized, but before the first photo taken. Yes, it would be nice to have programmatic control, but this is a life saver. It is also very handy to know that debugging can be activated/deactivated on a running app.

Comment: Enabling debug and disconnecting is also handy for tracing combination java and NDK development. Launch the app for debugging as an Android Native Application. Once the application is launched, the android application can be connected for debugging. By putting a breakpoint before the native code call, the java can be traced, then by disconnecting the debugger will fall into the native code breakpoint and allow native testing. I haven't found a clean way out of the native to resume java debugging, other than a java sleep long enough to re-attach after exiting the native.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of image did you use for the emulator?  The ARM System Images are particularly slow but the Intel x8 Atom System Image are much faster; something like 4x times faster.

The problem with the Intel System Images is that they are not available for all versions.

A second possibility would be to cut the size of your data for development & debugging purposes. It's very rare that someone will need a full complement of data for developping & debugging an application.

Comment: Yes, I had selected the ARM. Since I had a test setup, I went ahead and performed a speed test. Running the app without debugging, I choose the Galaxy Nexus (4.0.3) as the emulated machine, since it had ARM, MIPS and Atom. Compared to a real Android (MTK6575 Cortex A9 1.0GHz) which took 50 seconds. The MIPS was fastest at 5 minutes, the Atom second at 7:30 and the Arm slowest at 10 minutes. In debugging, the Mips would take 50 minutes.

Comment: Try the Atom with debugging.  You don't have to go to the full length; simply add a message after something like 1% of the file.  Check also the memory to see if you have given plenty of it.  You didn't show us how you were doing the insertion into the data array; maybe there is something to optimize there.

Comment: The question was about the debugger, which rich200313 answered.

Comment: The array is loaded from a windows file stored in little endian, so the data is currently loaded one byte at a time, with the byte order swapped as it loads (uggg). I know this needs to get redone, but there are bigger fish to fry till i get a round tuit. One big improvement I've made was swapping to a BufferedInputStream from a RandomAccessFile, which reduced the android debug down to 4 minutes and run down to 6 seconds. I've already deleted the VM, but I think it was 1024 meg memory.

Comment: One possibility would be to write down a version of the file using the Big endian mode the first time the program is run and read this second file thereafter for the following runnings.